# Scala sortBy descending with Option key

Tags: scala, sorting

I have the following object:

```
class Registration(
    domain: _root_.scala.Predef.String = "",
    registeredAt: Option[com.google.protobuf.timestamp.Timestamp] = None
)
```

and I need to sort the items by registeredAt desc.

I tried:

```
registrations.sortBy(_.registeredAt)(ord.reverse)

implicit def ord: Ordering[Option[Timestamp]] = Ordering.by(_.seconds)
```

However, I get an error on _.seconds because registeredAt is Option.

I also tried:

```
implicit val timeStampOrdering = new Ordering[Option[Timestamp]] {
    override def compare(x: Option[Timestamp], y: Option[Timestamp]): Int = x.map(_.seconds) compareTo y.map(_.seconds)
  }
```

But here I have an error that on compareTo

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an `Ordering[Timestamp]`, when what you need is

```
implicit def ord: Ordering[Option[Timestamp]] = Ordering.by(_.map(_.seconds))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is probably simplest to just extract the `seconds` in the `sortBy` call and avoid the need for a new `Ordering`. Negate the number to sort in reverse:

```
registrations.sortBy(_.registeredAt.fold(0)(0 - _.seconds))
```

(or `registeredAt.map(_.seconds).getOrElse(0)`)

Comment: ord is a method - I didn't understand how I can drop it from your answer

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll update the answer to remove `ord`

Answer (score 2):

You can use just an implicit `Ordering[Timestamp]`.

There is an implicit conversion in `Ordering` that will transform any `Ordering[T]` into `Ordering[Option[T]]`:

```scala
implicit def ord: Ordering[Timestamp] =
  Ordering.by(_. seconds)

implicitly[Ordering[Option[Timestamp]]] //we have this ordering
```